# Anyway to use Automapper when destination contains JArray property?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, automapper

Let say I have a source JObject:

```
var source = new JObject
                        {
                            { "XCV", Guit.NewGuid().ToString() },
                            { "store", "abc" },
                            { "productAId", "123" },
                            { "productAName", "xxxxxx" },
                            { "productBId", "456" },
                            { "productBName", "yyyyyy" },

                        };
```

And a custom model:

```
public class StoreProductModel
{
        public string TransactionId { get; set; }
        public JArray Data { get; set; }
}
```

If I transform StoreProductModel to json I am expecting the structure like:

```
{
  "transactionId": "...",
  "data": [
{
  "store": "abc",
  "productA": {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "xxxxxx",
    },
  "productB": {
      "id": "456",
      "name": "yyyyyy"
    }
}
]
}
```

What I tried as simple as possible:

```
#region JValue - object 
            CreateMap<JValue, object>().ConvertUsing(source => source.Value);
            #endregion
#region JObject - StoreProductModel

            CreateMap<JObject, StoreProductModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.TransactionId, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src["XCV"]); })
                .ForPath(dest => dest.Data[0]["productA"]["id"], opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src["productAId"]); })
                .ForPath(dest => dest.Data[0]["productA"]["name"], opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src["productAName"]); });
#endregion
```

Exception I got:

> "Only member accesses are allowed. dest => dest.Data.get_Item(0).get_Item("productA").get_Item("id") (Parameter 'destinationMember')"}    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

I do have an option to directly initialize the StoreProductModel and assign the values, but looking for some suggestions if it is possible to achieve the goal to map from a JObject source to a custom model with nested properties in JArray.

Automapper version: 12.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need any mapper in this case

```
var s = ...your source JObject

StoreProductModel storeProductModel = new StoreProductModel
{
    TransactionId = (string)s["XCV"],
    Data = new JArray{ new JObject {
                     {"store", s["store"] },
                     {"productA", new JObject { {"productId",   s["productAId"] },
                                                {"productName", s["productAName"] }}
                     },
                     {"productB", new JObject { {"productId",   s["productBId"] },
                                                {"productName", s["productBName"] }} }
                     }}
};
```

output

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(storeProductModel, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

{
  "TransactionId": "d1f88a3c-32c6-4a13-931b-3f819372b850",
  "Data": [
    {
      "store": "abc",
      "productA": {
        "productId": "123",
        "productName": "xxxxxx"
      },
      "productB": {
        "productId": "456",
        "productName": "yyyyyy"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```